# When breaking the fast what should be eaten/drank first?

Tags: halal-haram

We have to break the fast with water and dates, but which should be consumed first? The water or the dates?

Answer (score 2):

It’s preferred to break your fast with dates. But if you do not have dates, then water.

> “When one of you is fasting, he should break his fast with dates; but if he cannot get any, then (he should break his fast) with water, for water is purifying” 
>  **-Abu Dawood, 975**